# Java ActionEvent

Tags: java, jbutton, actionevent

I have problem with Java ActionEvent, becouse of my large code..

I Get this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The code of method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit
```

I have tried multiple ideas, but nothing work, for example:

I added One more ActionEvent

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
```

But got error:

```
Duplicate method actionPerformed(ActionEvent)
```

Eclipse shows me to, rename method tp "actionPerformed2" . If i do this, code works, but if I press button, nothing happens, made like this:

```
public void actionPerformed2(ActionEvent ae) {
if(ae.getSource() == jbtnBuildCarLv1){
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well since the message is just telling you that your method is too long, just split it up.

Also you can't just have two methods with the same name but if you rename one, it won't be the one that is gonna get called unless you do that manually.

Comment: How can i do that? Maybe you know some good tutorial?

Comment: Well if you don't know how to call a method you should maybe start with some beginner tutorials and not just jump into Action Events und Listeners... but hey a simple way to fix your problem without splitting into multiple methods would be to clean up your code. I find it very difficult to believe that you actually need every line you wrote... I mean I don't know what you're trying to do but even then: creating more sub-methods would be the way to go. Just think about a year from now when you try to read your code and understand it. You really think you can?

Comment: I know that, I made, that, but something don't work.. I think I understand that basics, but there are some thing that, i can't get. Code is so big, becouse im making Java 2D clicker game, with 200Car objects, 10 box objects, 10Player levels, etc.. Many stuff. :D All works. But this don't

Comment: You should not give each object it's own reference. I mean technically you have to but you should put them in lists, arrays, maps or something like that. That way you can iterate over them and have a lot less code but it will still do the same.

Comment: Once you use those, it doesn't matter if you have 10, 100 or even 100.000 cars, the code will remain exactly the same size.

Comment: Thank you very, very much. Didn't know this. :)